# Can we create WPF application using MVC or MVP?

Tags: wpf, windows, model-view-controller, mvp

In a interview,i had been asked to a question that,
Can we create WPF application using MVC or MVP design pattern or practice. I said MVC or MVP is a design pattern to develop loosely coupled application. we'll use MVC,MVP or MVVM based on given scenario,context,technology and platform of application.

If We can Create WPF application using MVC or MVP,if you have any good example in form of code or PoC, then please share or explain.

Comment: After searching for answer i have found one useful link.

 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23241/Using-MVC-to-Unit-Test-WPF-Applications

Comment: this link is also useful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228214/Understanding-Basics-of-UI-Design-Pattern-MVC-MVP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC, MVP and MVVM all are UI design pattern. There is no restriction on using these pattern with WPF. But if we are using MVVM pattern we can take advantage of WPF feature like data binding etc..

Reference: - [MVVM vs MVP vs MVC](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained/)

Comment: You can use data binding even with when using MVC on WPF.